# Keeping a same format and logging for all the errors in PHP

Tags: php, format, logging

I have multiple classes and what I wanna do is that have a consitent style for errors. for example for mysql errors, template class errors, and stuff.

Also what could be a better way of exiting with an error other that die("");

Should I define my own function and then put die in there and the style message with that function as well as die();

Also, if I want to log errors such as

```
Error | line number | script name | if a class then where was it called that caused error | memory usage | cpu usage
```

thanks....

Comment: Why do you need distinct errors for mysql and template? Does it make any difference for the end user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) for all your specific error formatting needs. You will need to define a custom function to pretty print in your desired format:

```
set_error_handler("my_errors");

function my_errors($errno,$errstr,$file,$line,$context) {
    print "<div class=error>"
        . "Error $errno | $line | $file name | ... | ... | ... "
        . "</div>";
}
```

For that extra information that *you* want, you will have to use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to find out details, or [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/memory_get_usage).

If you want to write the stuff to a file, then just use `file_put_contents("log.txt", $string, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);` instead of the direct `print`.

Comment: printing errors to the browser (e.g. with a full call stack)in a development environment can be a perfectly acceptable idea. What's so wrong with it?

Comment: @Pekka he is apparently talking not about development environment. he is asking about exiting with an error, so, it's about end-user experience.

Comment: @Col granted, the question could use some more clarification.